# How to make a responsive image animation in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I wan't to make a UI which would look like this,

[image]

My intention is to fill the white circle around the arrow with green colour in a typical loading bar animation. The amount filled in green should correspond to the distance shown below the arrow.
(lower the distance, higher the green fill)

What is the easiest approach to achieve this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this with a `<ProgressBar/>`. As `progressDrawable` you assign a drawable.
With `progress` you can set the current progress which represents your distance.

Add this to your layout:

```
<layout>
    ...
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@id/distance_circle_ui"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:max="@{viewmodel.foobar.distance}"
        android:progress="@{viewmodel.foobar.distance_progress}"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/distance_circle_drawable"
        android:intermediate="false" />
    ...
</layout>
```

I have used binding here. It would also be possible to set the progress attribute programmatically.

The drawable (/res/drawable/distance_circle_drawable.xml) looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="270"
    android:toDegrees="270">
    <shape
        android:innerRadius="125dp"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thickness="15dp"
        android:useLevel="true">
        <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    </shape>
</rotate>
```

For me this looks very "easy" :)

Comment: Worked like a charm :) Thank you. Just a side question, do you know how to make the circle drawable non-transparent though? want to fill the inner circle with black :)

Comment: I do not think this is possibile with one drawable. But you can stack multiple drawables. You can use a black oval then add a white ring and then the green progress ring.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new view by `<ProgressBar/>` but if progress is not important you can use `gif` file

- https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-display-animated-gif-images-in-android

but beacase progress is important you can `<ImageVew>` and some images for creating a new progress bar isn't very hard.